# Flutter with STM32MP157 on Kirkstone branch

Tags: flutter, embedded-linux, yocto

I was trying to run flutter on my discovery board.
[I followed this yaml. file for kirkstone branch](https://github.com/meta-flutter/meta-flutter/blob/dunfell/.github/workflows/dunfell-stm32mp15.yml)

But in the end I get error and it can be seen below:

> ERROR: flutter-engine-runtimerelease-git-r0 do_install: ExpansionError('do_install', "\n    install -D -m0644 ...
> ERROR: Task (virtual:runtimerelease:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/meta-flutter/recipes-graphics/flutter-engine/flutter-engine_git.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'

and Here is my local.conf since I am not using dunfell branch like in the example.

```
ACCEPT_EULA_stm32mp15-disco = "1"
#DL_DIR = "/home/gencay/dev/dl"
#SSTATE_DIR = "/home/gencay/dev/sstate"
#SSTATE_MIRRORS = "file://.* file:///home/gencay/dev/sstate"
GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES = "en_US.UTF-8"
IMAGE_LINGUAS = "en-us"
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK:append = " nativesdk-flutter-sdk"
CLANGSDK = "1"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_flutter-engine-runtimerelease="flutter-engine-runtimerelease"
FLUTTER_RUNTIME_pn-flutter-drm-gbm-backend = "debug"
FLUTTER_RUNTIME_pn-flutter-wayland-client = "debug"
INHERIT:remove = "uninative"
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " x11 wayland opengl "
#PACKAGECONFIG_pn-ivi-homescreen-debug = "transparency"
#PACKAGECONFIG_pn-ivi-homescreen-profile = "transparency"
#PACKAGECONFIG_pn-ivi-homescreen-release = "transparency"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL:remove = " packagegroup-framework-core "
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL:remove = " packagegroup-framework-tools "
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL:remove = " packagegroup-framework-core-extra "
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL:remove = " packagegroup-st-demo "
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL:remove = " gtk+3-demo "
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " \
          weston weston-init \
          flutter-gallery \
          adwaita-icon-theme-cursors \
          xdg-user-dirs \
          flutter-drm-gbm-backend \
          flutter-wayland-client \
          avahi-daemon \
          flutter-pi \
          ntp ntp-tickadj \
          infos-openstlinux \
          fbgrab \
          tiff libv4l rc-keymaps packagegroup-gstreamer1-0 \
          gstreamer1.0 \
          gstreamer1.0-libav \
          gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
          gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
          gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
          gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
          "
LICENSE_FLAGS_ACCEPTED = "commercial"
```

What can be the problem or missing package?
Whole error log file is below:

```
    ERROR: flutter-engine-git-r0 do_install: ExpansionError('do_install', "\n    install -D -m0644 /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/src/out/linux_release_arm/so.unstripped/libflutter_engine.so \\\n        /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image/usr/lib/libflutter_engine.so\n\n    if ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'desktop-embeddings', 'true', 'false', d)}; then\n        install -m0644 /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/src/out/linux_release_arm/so.unstripped/libflutter_linux_gtk.so /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image/usr/lib\n    fi\n\n    install -D -m0644 /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/src/out/linux_release_arm/flutter_embedder.h \\\n        /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image/usr/include/flutter_embedder.h\n\n    install -D -m0644 /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/src/out/linux_release_arm/icudtl.dat \\\n        /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image/usr/share/flutter/icudtl.dat\n\n    # create SDK\n    install -D -m0755 /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/src/out/linux_release_arm/clang_x64/gen_snapshot \\\n        /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image/usr/share/flutter/sdk/clang_x64/gen_snapshot\n\n    cd /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/src/flutter\n    echo `git rev-parse HEAD` > /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image/usr/share/flutter/sdk/engine.version\n    echo ${FLUTTER_ENGINE_REPO_URL} >> /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image/usr/share/flutter/sdk/engine.version\n    echo ${@get_flutter_sdk_version(d)} >> /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image/usr/share/flutter/sdk/flutter_sdk.version\n\n    cd /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/image//usr/share/flutter\n    zip -r engine_sdk.zip sdk\n    rm -rf sdk\n", URLError(gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')))
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/temp/log.do_install.3870646
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/meta-clang/recipes-devtools/clang/compiler-rt_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/meta-clang/recipes-devtools/clang/libcxx_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.67.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-support/curl/curl_7.82.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-extended/zip/zip_3.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.10.4.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-graphics/fontconfig/fontconfig_2.13.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/meta-flutter/recipes-devtools/depot-tools/depot-tools-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-extended/pbzip2/pbzip2_1.1.13.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-support/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20211016.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/meta-clang/recipes-devtools/clang/clang-cross_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.35.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['pkgconfig-native', 'compiler-rt', 'patch-native', 'libcxx', 'quilt-native', 'curl-native', 'zip-native', 'python3-native', 'fontconfig', 'depot-tools-native', 'pseudo-native', 'pbzip2-native', 'ca-certificates-native', 'clang-cross-arm', 'glibc', 'libtool-native', 'gcc-runtime', 'libgcc', 'attr-native', 'openssl-native', 'zlib-native', 'xz-native', 'libtirpc-native', 'libnsl2-native', 'readline-native', 'util-linux-libuuid-native', 'libffi-native', 'gdbm-native', 'bzip2-native', 'ncurses-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'util-linux', 'expat', 'zlib', 'freetype', 'clang-native', 'binutils-cross-arm', 'linux-libc-headers', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'perl-native', 'libxcrypt', 'ncurses', 'opkg-utils', 'bash-completion', 'util-linux-libuuid', 'libcap-ng', 'libpam', 'libpng', 'swig-native', 'cmake-native', 'libedit-native', 'binutils-native', 'libxml2-native', 'flex-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'flex', 'cracklib', 'libpcre-native', 'zstd-native', 'm4-native']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
ERROR: Task (/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/meta-flutter/recipes-graphics/flutter-engine/flutter-engine_git.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'

DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/meta-clang/recipes-devtools/clang/compiler-rt_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.35.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-extended/pbzip2/pbzip2_1.1.13.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.67.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-support/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20211016.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/meta-clang/recipes-devtools/clang/libcxx_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/meta-clang/recipes-devtools/clang/clang-cross_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-support/curl/curl_7.82.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-extended/zip/zip_3.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/meta-flutter/recipes-devtools/depot-tools/depot-tools-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-graphics/fontconfig/fontconfig_2.13.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.10.4.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['compiler-rt', 'glibc', 'patch-native', 'pbzip2-native', 'quilt-native', 'ca-certificates-native', 'pseudo-native', 'libcxx', 'clang-cross-arm', 'curl-native', 'zip-native', 'depot-tools-native', 'fontconfig', 'pkgconfig-native', 'python3-native', 'libgcc', 'gcc-runtime', 'linux-libc-headers', 'attr-native', 'libtool-native', 'bzip2-native', 'openssl-native', 'clang-native', 'binutils-cross-arm', 'zlib-native', 'xz-native', 'freetype', 'zlib', 'util-linux', 'expat', 'libffi-native', 'libnsl2-native', 'readline-native', 'util-linux-libuuid-native', 'libtirpc-native', 'gdbm-native', 'ncurses-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'perl-native', 'libxml2-native', 'libedit-native', 'swig-native', 'binutils-native', 'cmake-native', 'flex-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'libpng', 'opkg-utils', 'libxcrypt', 'libcap-ng', 'util-linux-libuuid', 'ncurses', 'bash-completion', 'libpam', 'libpcre-native', 'zstd-native', 'm4-native', 'cracklib', 'flex']
DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
```

Comment: Can you at least share the whole error ? It should be a file where the error is stored you can find the path in the error. Share it

Comment: Hello, thank you for your attention. I edited the post and added the whole error message.

Comment: now share this /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp15-disco/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine/git-r0/temp/log.do_install.3870646

Comment: Sorry for late response I had to delete build for low disk space, I rebuilt it and instead of /flutter-engine now the error is on /flutter-engine-runtimerelease and the log on the correspounding file is added